# Importing a large number of rows into Postgres with duplicate key violations

Tags: sql, postgresql, import, key, postgresql-copy

Is it possible in Postgres 9.6 to get `on duplicate key` UPSERT functionality using the `COPY` command? I have a CSV file that I'm importing into Postgres, but it may contain some duplicate key violations, so the `COPY` command gives an error and terminates when it encounters them.

The file is very large so it might not be possible to pre-process it in application code (in order to handle rows that might lead to duplicate key violations) since all keys might not fit into memory.

What's the best way to import a very large number of rows into Postgres that might contain duplicate key violations?

Comment: copy has not upsert. you can copy to other table and then insert differece

Comment: @VaoTsun Could you please post an answer with an example of what you mean? I'm not sure how to implement the 'insert difference' part.

Comment: I did. in your case you have UK, so you have to insert from `left outer join...where original.uk_att is null`. if you want to insert rows that are different at all( all columns), use `except` in similar way

Answer (score 3):

sample:

```
t=# create table s90(i int primary key, t text);
CREATE TABLE
t=# insert into s90 select 1,'a';
INSERT 0 1
t=# copy s90 from stdin delimiter ',';
Enter data to be copied followed by a newline.
End with a backslash and a period on a line by itself.
>> 1,'b'
>> 2,'c'
>> \.
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "s90_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (i)=(1) already exists.
CONTEXT:  COPY s90, line 1
```

workaround with copy:

```
t=# create table s91 as select * from s90 where false;;
SELECT 0
t=# copy s91 from stdin delimiter ',';
Enter data to be copied followed by a newline.
End with a backslash and a period on a line by itself.
>> 1,'b'
>> 2,'c'
>> \.
COPY 2
t=# with p as (select s91.* from s91 left outer join s90 on s90.i=s91.i where s90.i is null)
insert into s90 select * from p;
INSERT 0 1
t=# select * from s90;
 i |  t
---+-----
 1 | a
 2 | 'c'
(2 rows)
```